# Copy a file from lambda function AWS to an Azure machine

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using lambda function in AWS to trigger some data, and i want to create a file which contains this data and send it to another machine in Azure, i want to know if that is possible, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

- *yes, as per the official documentation you can transfer files from AWS lambda to Azure blob storage using SFTP gateway.*
- *Once you create SFTP gateway you need to setup 2 folder with each one pointing to different locations.*
  [image]
- *Here is the [documentation](https://help.thorntech.com/docs/sftp-gateway-azure-3.0/azure-blob-to-s3/) related to connection with SFTP gateway.*
- *And few related documentations with related discussions.*

1. [Lambda to blob](https://thorntech.com/multi-cloud-connection-transfer-files-between-aws-s3-and-azure-blob-storage/)
2. [File Transfer](https://thorntech.com/simple-cloud-file-transfer-aws-s3-azure-blob/)