# Move File - AWS S3 to Azure Blob Storage using AWS Lambda - Connection Issue

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, azure-blob-storage, file-transfer

Working on simple use case of transferring a file from S3 to Azure Blob Storage container using Azure SDK in Java based AWS Lambda. But before going to file transfer, I wanted to test the connectivity itself from my Lambda so I decided to first try and list the blobs in a container.

I am using "Shared Access Signature" token for authenticating access to Azure Blob Storage container. Faced lot of challenges to establish the connection on the local but at last I was able to make successful connection and finally I was able to list all the blobs in a given container.

Now, when I merged the same code to my Lambda and run it. It is giving me Authorization error as below.

[Lambda Exception Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3hZG.png)

Since I am new to Azure, can someone help me in understanding if there is any authentication, network configuration missing to establish this connection or am I fundamentally missing something.

[Code this is working on Eclipse IDE on Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYMbK.png)

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you seen this approach?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72432875/1080804

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an Authentication Failure. This includes the possibility that the SAS (Shared access signature) token you are using to connect is missing one or more permissions to execute a particular action that is needed by the `BlobContainerClient`. The actions are: Read, Write, Delete, List, Add, Create, Process, Immutable storage, Permanent delete. You also have different types of services you can interact with: blob, file, queue, table. Finally, when the SAS token is created, it can be configured with an expiration date, a set of allowed IP addresses, limited to use only a certain protocol and choose a signing key. Perhaps one of these conditions is not allowing the same code to behave in the same way when it is executed from two different locations?